# No module named 'ipywidgets' error when running IPyhon.widgets

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have IPython 4.0.1 installed. I cannot figure out the cause of the following error -

```
>>> from IPython.html import widgets
>>> k = widgets.Box
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\shimmodule.py", line 90, in __getattr__
    return import_item(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ImportError: No module named 'ipywidgets'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    k = widgets.Box
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\shimmodule.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: Box
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `pip install ipywidgets`

Comment: oops. thank you. seriously this didn't cross my mind :-)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Between IPython 3 and IPython 4, a number of components were split into separate packages (http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/04/15/the-big-split/).  Widgets were one of the features effected.

You can install ipywidgets through the standard channels (as Yashu Seth suggests):

```
pip install ipywidgets
# or
conda install ipywidgets
```

And you should get in the habit of not importing widgets from IPython.html, since the old library structure is being deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

ipywidgets is not installed with IPython. Just install it.

```
pip install ipywidgets
```